# Deploy nginx with helm in non-default namespace

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, openshift, helm3

I have seen so many issues with Helm and default namespace here on SO that it is embarrassing to post yet another one. I believe I reviewed the ones I saw and did not find a solution to my problem.

Helm version is 3.9.3
Kubernetes: OpenShift 4.9

I create an nginx chart by simply doing:

```
helm create disco
```

When I deploy this application in default project/namespace, it works fine. However, when I deploy it in non-default workspace, it fails.

My command for deploying in non-default workspace:

```
oc new-project helm-sandbox
helm install disco . --namespace helm-sandbox
```

The CLI appears to indicate that the deployment succeeded. But the pod keeps having CrashLoopBackoff.

The pod logs show following error message:

```
nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2
2022/09/08 02:00:19 [emerg] 1#1: mkdir() "/var/cache/nginx/client_temp" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: [emerg] mkdir() "/var/cache/nginx/client_temp" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

Any idea why this is failing on me?

Comment: why do u want to mention the namespace in helm ? you could mention it along with the template right ? Also i think u need to run nginx as a privileged pod

Comment: In the default namespace nginx deploys just fine and it doesn't need priviledge pod. So there must be a way to do similarly in other namespaces. @sidharthvijayakumar I am not sure what you mean by "mention the namespace in helm". All I want is deploy nginx in a non-default namespace. Anyway that allows me to do that is welcome.

Comment: If you use helm charts templates must have a deployment.yml cant you add the namespace in metadata and then do helm install ?

Comment: Sorry. That doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share more details like the docker image used , deployment manifest ?

Comment: It is whatever I get when I do "helm create disco". No single change.

Comment: The message said you have no permissions. Please check what SCC a service account has.

Comment: Thanks for helping on this guys. I am really confused. This is the SCC of the default service user used for the deployment: https://pasteboard.co/mmp0CkpNr3ER.png.

Comment: @hiroyukik you actually put me on the right path. The solution to the issue is described here: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/security-context-constraint-permissions. Please consider providing an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, every Pod use `default` service account on OpenShift and the service account is attached `restricted` SCC.

Additionally, UID in Pod is randomly chose from the range which is defined at `openshift.io/sa.scc.uid-range` annotation in the namespace which the Pod is defined.

So, the `random` UID may have no permission to write the `/var/cache/nginx/` directory.

However, Change UID with anyuid or nonroot SCCs to the service account used by Pod is not good idea unless the Pod needs strong permission to work.

If you want the cache directory is an ephemeral directory, mounting emptyDir or ephemeral volume are better to solve it.

If you want persist it, mount a Persistent Volume as `/var/cache/nginx`.

If you need to change UID, give anyuid or nonroot SCC to a service account. But, giving a SCC to pre-defined SCC is not good. So if you need to use a SCC other than `restricted`, you should create a service account and use it to start your Pod.

Hopefully, those are helpful to solve the issue.